# YOLOv8 Matrix confusion

Tags: python, yolov8

I have question about results of YOLOv8 model , after the training of the model it results in a 3-dimensional confusion matrix taking the background as a class knowing that I have a binary classification my project is classification of preforms whether it is defect or not. What can be the raisaon of appearance of this class "backgroud" and how I can solve it ? if you help me I would be grateful.

i need to undrestand reason of prediction class"background" when i don't declared in my model